# How to reorder results after serchkick finds a proper result?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, searchkick

When I do in rails console this: `posts = Post.active.search('lorem').records` it gives me this: `` Post Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`id` IN (3, 1, 2) LIMIT 11 `` But when I do `posts.pluck(:id)` the result is: `[1, 2, 3]`. So, as you can see, the order is not the same, as it is in a query, it should be `[3, 1, 2]`. How can I reorder the result, so it will be `[3, 1, 2]`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a raw MySQL query which will generate the output you expect:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE
    id IN (3, 1, 2)
ORDER BY
    FIELD(id, 3, 1, 2)
LIMIT 11
```

I have little knowledge about ActiveRecord but I would expect that you would need to use raw SQL for the above `ORDER BY` clause, and possibly for the entire query.  One option here would be to run the entire raw query:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ... ORDER BY FIELD(id, 3, 1, 2) LIMIT 11"
records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```